# When this function will be triggered because trap commnad?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Given the following code:

```
set -e
my_func() {
    echo "Error.. some msg"
    exit
}
trap 'my_func ${LINENO}' ERR
```

1. What are the arguments that this function (`my_func`) gets while have error (apart of the argument $LINENO as the first argument, but what are the other arguments?
2. When this function will be triggered ? (in which cases of errors?)

Comment: Have you tried finding the answers in bash documentation?

Comment: What part of `man bash` don't you understand?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes but it's written there in genral words without examples

Comment: Could you be more specific? What words exactly are generic in the documentation? Examples to which explanations would you like to have examples to?

Comment: @KamilCuk Sure. "If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a pipeline, a list, or a compound command returns a non-zero exit status". I looking for examples that will explain these words better..

Comment: pipeline `echo 1 | cat` https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines , list https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists `echo 1 && echo 2` , compund command https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands `if true; do echo 1; fi`. The documentation also explains what is the exit status of every of these, for example for pipeline `The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, unless the pipefail option is enabled [...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the arguments that this function (my_func) gets while have error (apart of the argument $LINENO as the first argument, but what are the other arguments?

That is... easy to check. The following code outputs 1:

```
$ ( set -e; f() { echo $#; }; trap 'f $LINENO' ERR; false )
1
```

There is only one argument.

> When this function will be triggered ?

**Mostly** when a command exits with non-zero exit status. Before using `set -e` required reading: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 .

> in which cases of errors?

Depends on the particular command. For example, `false` command exits with non-zero exit status, it's not an "error" for *that* command to do that. For example `grep` exits with 1 if no lines were selected, and with 2 if an error occured.

---

> "If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a pipeline, a list, or a compound command returns a non-zero exit status". I looking for examples that will explain these words better.

```
cat file | grep '['
```

This pipeline will exit with 2 exit status, because `[` is invalid regular expression, which will make `grep` fail. The exit status of pipeline is the exit status of the last command, so it is grep, so it exits with 2, and triggers `ERR` trap.

(Additionally, because there is no file named `file` on my working directory, `cat` will also fail, if `pipefail` option is enabled the pipeline will fail with the non-zero exit status of `cat`. That will also trigger `ERR`)

```
[[ -e file ]] && [[ -r file ]]
```

Because there is no file `file` on my working directory, this list will fail at the first `[[` command, and the list will exit with the non-zero exit status returned by first `[[` command. And will trigger `ERR` trap.

```
if [[ -e /dev ]]; then grep '['; fi
```

The exit status of `if` compound command is zero if no body was executed, otherwise is the exit status of the last command in the body. Because `grep '['` will fail, the exit status of `if` will be non-zero, and that will also trigger `ERR`.